# Remove specific items Python Beautiful Soup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

How can I strip this out and leave the rest using python and beautiful soup, other items in `td` need to be kept

```
<td style="background:#aaccff" width="50"></td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="150">Device Type</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="115">IP Address</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="100">Device Name</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="215">Notes</td>
<td width="50"></td>
```

here is the full code

```
<td style="background:#aaccff" width="50"></td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="150">Device Type</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="115">IP Address</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="100">Device Name</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="215">Notes</td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="left" width="150">AudioCodes Gateway</td>
<td align="left" width="115">172.31.31.2</td>
<td align="left" width="100"></td>
<td align="left" width="215">FXO</td>
<td style="background:#aaccff" width="50"></td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="150">Device Type</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="115">IP Address</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="100">Device Name</td>
<td align="left" style="background:#aaccff" width="215">Notes</td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="left" width="150">IC Server</td>
<td align="left" width="115">172.31.56.151</td>
<td align="left" width="100">IND056GIC151</td>
<td align="left" width="215">NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.151</td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="left" width="150">IC Server</td>
<td align="left" width="115">172.31.56.152</td>
<td align="left" width="100">IND056GIC152</td>
<td align="left" width="215">NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.152</td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="left" width="150">Media Server</td>
<td align="left" width="115">IND1106HMS07</td>
<td align="left" width="100">IND1106HMS07</td>
<td align="left" width="215"></td>
<td width="50"></td>
<td align="left" width="150">Media Server</td>
<td align="left" width="115">IND1106HMS07</td>
<td align="left" width="100">IND1106HMS07</td>
<td align="left" width="215"></td>
```

here is what I have so far code wise

```
from ntlm import HTTPNtlmAuthHandler
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests, os, bleach, urllib2, cookielib

os.system('clear')
user = 'user'
password = "pass"
url = "url"

cookies = cookielib.CookieJar()
passman = urllib2.HTTPPasswordMgrWithDefaultRealm()
passman.add_password(None, url, user, password)
opener = urllib2.build_opener(urllib2.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookies),HTTPNtlmAuthHandler.HTTPNtlmAuthHandler(passman))

pagedata=opener.open(url)
soup=BeautifulSoup(pagedata)

def myfunction(b):
table = b.find('ul', {'class': 'dfwp-column dfwp-list'})

for a in table.findAll('a'):
    [a.decompose() for a in table("a")]
for tr in table.findAll('tr'):
    for td in tr.findAll('td'):

        print td

myfunction(soup)
```

Here is the current output

Device Type
IP Address
Device Name
Notes

AudioCodes Gateway
172.31.31.2

FXO

Device Type
IP Address
Device Name
Notes

IC Server
172.31.56.151
IND056GIC151
NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.151

IC Server
172.31.56.152
IND056GIC152
NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.152

Media Server
IND1106HMS07
IND1106HMS07

Media Server
IND1106HMS07
IND1106HMS07

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"?

Comment: strip them out so they aren't displayed in in the final output

Comment: It isn't clear to me what why the tags you want removed are selected vs. the ones to keep.

Comment: What does your code so far *do*?

Comment: wanted to remove the Device Type IP Address Device Name Notes and the extra spaces

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally when people ask about how to "remove" something with `bs4`, they're really just asking how to not include it in a `find` operation.

You want to exclude the extra spaces (i.e. tags with `tag.text == ''`) and those four "column header" tags.  You can do the latter through CSS selectors, but the former needs to be explicitly filtered.  So it's easiest to do both at once, and is more declarative in my opinion:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(that_long_html_you_gave)

blacklist = {'Device Type','IP Address','Device Name','Notes'}

table = soup.body # to match your variable name.  I think.

table.find_all(lambda tag: tag.text and tag.text not in blacklist)
Out[45]: 
[<td align="left" width="150">AudioCodes Gateway</td>,
 <td align="left" width="115">172.31.31.2</td>,
 <td align="left" width="215">FXO</td>,
 <td align="left" width="150">IC Server</td>,
 <td align="left" width="115">172.31.56.151</td>,
 <td align="left" width="100">IND056GIC151</td>,
 <td align="left" width="215">NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.151</td>,
 <td align="left" width="150">IC Server</td>,
 <td align="left" width="115">172.31.56.152</td>,
 <td align="left" width="100">IND056GIC152</td>,
 <td align="left" width="215">NAT'd IP = PENDING MPLS, Voice IP = 172.31.52.152</td>,
 <td align="left" width="150">Media Server</td>,
 <td align="left" width="115">IND1106HMS07</td>,
 <td align="left" width="100">IND1106HMS07</td>,
 <td align="left" width="150">Media Server</td>,
 <td align="left" width="115">IND1106HMS07</td>,
 <td align="left" width="100">IND1106HMS07</td>]
```